# Mathematica Progression Path from Apprentice to Guru

Tags: education

There's an [excellent set of responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573135/python-progression-path-from-apprentice-to-guru) to a question about learning Python on stack overflow. As there seems to be a large number of Mathematica experts here, it seems of value (to me at least) to ask the same about Mathematica.

The strict nature of these sites might prohibit such a question but I think it is likely to become one of "historical significance".

Comment: WReach wrote a good answer [here (45829)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/45958/731).

Comment: I found this a surprisingly hard question to answer. WReach' excellent answer, linked above, is worth careful consideration.  Generally,  I'd follow an algorithm similar to this: 1. Master the core language.  2. Practice. Solve your own problems using it. 3. Read lots of code (on this site and elsewhere), and compare to your experiences. 4. Work on something large enough to learn larger-scale program design and development in Mathematica.  5. Go to 1.  For mastering the core language, I gave some recommendations [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7596/81).

Comment: In terms of finding good resources here, [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice) is the obvious place with tons of structured information / links. Also, you may want to look at all answers that received the "Good answer" or "Guru" badge, pick those that interest you, and learn from them. If / when I have the time, I may contribute a longer answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programming paradigm change](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45829/programming-paradigm-change)

Comment: Hi Kris; "We are all ready to win, just as we are born knowing only life. It is defeat that you must learn to prepare for." You must also face the cruel fact that not everyone can make the journey from apprentice to master. I have known people who spent their entire lives trying to master one discipline or the other and after 50 years remained a noob. But, you have to try anyway,